# How to use LAG function and get the numbers in percentages in SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I have a table with columns below

Employee(linked_lylty_card_nbr, prod_nbr, tot_amt_incld_gst, start_txn_date, main_total_size, tota_size_uom)

Below is the respective table

```
linked_lylty_card_nbr, prod_nbr, tot_amt_incld_gst, start_txn_date, main_total_size, tota_size_uom
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    3.1600  2021-11-10                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2.6800  2021-11-20                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2.6900  2021-12-21                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    3.1600  2021-12-30                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    5.3700  2022-01-14                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2.6800  2022-01-16                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2.4900  2022-01-19                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    3.4600  2022-02-26                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   3.9800  2022-05-26                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   3.9800  2022-06-11                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    3.9800  2022-06-14                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    3.9800  2022-06-24                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   4.4600  2022-07-30                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    4.0100  2022-08-02                  500.0000    ML
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    4.0100  2022-09-01                  500.0000    ML
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   3.9800  2022-09-08                  500.0000    ML
```

I'm trying to get the change in the volume per each visit in % i.e. percentage, for example if 1100000000006296409 is linked_lylty_card_nbr then for start_txn_date 2021-11-10 main_total_size is 500, then for the same customer for 2021-11-20 the main_total_size is 500, there's no difference and no of days it's taking for the linked_lylty_card_nbr to return and get the product in % i.e. percentage. Below is the SQL query i've written

```
SELECT 
  linked_lylty_card_nbr, 
  prod_nbr, 
  start_txn_date, 
  main_total_size, 
  total_size_uom, 
  (
    main_total_size - LAG(main_total_size, 1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY linked_lylty_card_nbr 
      ORDER BY 
        start_txn_date
    )) / main_total_size AS change_in_volume_per_visit, 
  (
    start_txn_date - LAG(start_txn_date, 1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY linked_lylty_card_nbr 
      ORDER BY 
        start_txn_date
    )) / main_total_size AS change_in_days_per_visit 
FROM 
  Employee
ORDER BY 
  linked_lylty_card_nbr, 
  start_txn_date
```

The output is below

```
linked_lylty_card_nbr  prod_nbr start_txn_date main_total_size tota_size_uomm  change_in_volume_per_visit    change_in_days_per_visit
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2021-12-21  500.0   ML      
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-01-14  1000.0  ML                             0.5  0.024
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-01-19  500.0   ML                            -1.0  0.01
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-06-14  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.292
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-06-24  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.02
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-08-02  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.078
1100000000001959800 83563-EA    2022-09-01  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.06
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2021-11-10  500.0   ML      
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2021-11-20  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.02
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2021-12-30  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.08
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2022-01-16  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.034
1100000000006296409 83563-EA    2022-02-26  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.082
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   2022-05-26  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.178
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   2022-06-11  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.032
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   2022-07-30  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.098
1100000000006296409 607577-EA   2022-09-08  500.0   ML                             0.0  0.08
```

From the above output, the change_in_volume_per_visit column, 2nd row has value 0.5. But it must be 1 if 500 is jumping to 1000 as in main_total_size 1st row has 500 and 2nd row has 1000 and Can anyone please confirm whether change_in_days_per_visit values are correct or not?

Comment: Mysql and snowflake are two differentproducts. Which one do you use?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms